# Why am I getting values outside polygon with geoIntersect

Tags: mongodb, polygon, geospatial

I am using mongodb with polygons stored with geometry in this format

```
"geometry" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ 2.0315, 85.8546219515 ], [ 2.0315, 86.1673780485 ], [ 1.7185, 86.1673780485 ], [ 1.7185, 85.8546219515 ], [ 2.0315, 85.8546219515 ] ] ] }
```

I am trying to use geoIntersect and query a rectangle polygon using something like this:

```
find({geometry:{$geoIntersects:{$geometry:{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates":[ [[12,20], [13,20], [13,18], [12,18], [12,20]]]}}}})
```

When I do small queries like that, the results are fine, but when I expand to really large boxes:

```
find({geometry:{$geoIntersects:{$geometry:{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates":[ [[-166.2890625,46.55886030311719], [-166.2890625,47.39834920035926], [12.12890625,47.39834920035926], [12.12890625,46.55886030311719], [-166.2890625,46.55886030311719]]]}}}})
```

then I start getting really odd results like

```
"geometry" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ 2.9684999999999997, 85.54162195149999 ], [ 2.9684999999999997, 85.8543780485 ], [ 2.6555, 85.8543780485 ], [ 2.6555, 85.54162195149999 ], [ 2.9684999999999997, 85.54162195149999 ] ] ] }
```

I am only returned a few polygons (4 total) from the db that are actually inside my input polygon:

```
"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[12.343499999999999,47.1416219515],[12.343499999999999,47.454378048500004],[12.0305,47.454378048500004],[12.0305,47.1416219515],[12.343499999999999,47.1416219515]]]}}
"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[12.343499999999999,46.829621951499995],[12.343499999999999,47.1423780485],[12.0305,47.1423780485],[12.0305,46.829621951499995],[12.343499999999999,46.829621951499995]]]}}
"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-166.0935,46.5166219515],[-166.0935,46.829378048500004],[-166.4065,46.829378048500004],[-166.4065,46.5166219515],[-166.0935,46.5166219515]]]}}
"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-166.0935,46.829621951499995],[-166.0935,47.1423780485],[-166.4065,47.1423780485],[-166.4065,46.829621951499995],[-166.0935,46.829621951499995]]]}}
```

I shouldn't have any latitudes in the 80's with my input. I don't know where these are coming from.  They make up the majority of what is returned. (847/851 results)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the polygon fits in one hemisphere. From the [$geoIntersects docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#op._S_geoIntersects),

> Any geometry specified with GeoJSON to $geoIntersects queries, must fit within a single hemisphere.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What about when I use smaller areas? I found that I start getting incorrect values once my longitude range is > 8.5 degrees--just less extreme distortion. Any thoughts on why that might happen? I can post an input/output example if necessary.